# How to change the value of heading columns based on a parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I created a report where I want to show the heading of a column based on a parameter. I tried using both table and matrix format, but I'm unable to reduce year.

```
year=2013
```

For example if I choose `2013` in the report this means it will show the last 10 years in the repor, i.e. `2013,2012,2011,2010,2009,2008,` up until `2002`.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read, and you haven't told us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far. Show us some code, be specific about the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to query a database and display the results in a table with a column per year. You can do this by using by using a Matrix object and Column Groups

Add your Matrix object by drag and dropping. Select the Column Group | Group Properties and add a Group Expression.

Use the following code as your Group Expression.

```
=Year(Fields!Date.Value)
```

Comment: hi tried this. still i am facing the same error
Country Name  Population in '2012' Population in '2011' Population in '2010' Population in '2009' Population in '2008'
India  20000 18000 16000 14000 12000
China  22000 20000 18000 16000 14000
USA  18000 16000 14000 12000 10000
Russia  16000 14000 12000 10000 8000
Australia 14000 12000 10000 8000 6000

Comment: You're not really clear what the problem is but I suspect you need to add a row group for the country, group by the country name field and you should be okay. If this doesn't can you post how your data displays and be more clear what you need it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Two fold I'd think:

1. Alter your sql to accept the parameter and get the bast 10 years in column names 1, 2, etc.
2. Then use an expression in the header or title similar to `=@Parameter!par.Value - Cdec(Data!1.Value)` to show headers for 2013 to 2002.

I hope I was clear?